# How to remove Special price and Regular price label from product detail page?

Tags: layout, frontend, magento-2.1.7

I tried,

```
app/locale/en_US/Mage_catalog.csv
```

Where to find this path in **Magento 2**?

I tried,

1. Stores –> Configuration –> ADVANCED –> Developer –> Magento 
        Developer –> Translate Inline
2. Change "Enabled for Frontend" from 'No' to 'Yes'.
3. Press Save Config
4. Refresh Cache

[image]

But how to remove red lines?

Actually I have not understood properly. Can anyone explain briefly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do:

> Stores –> Configuration –> ADVANCED –> Developer –> Magento Developer
>   –>

Translate Inline

> Change "Enabled for Frontend" from 'Yes' to 'No'

**Press Save Config**

Refresh Cache

Comment: after changing please deploy then changes will be reflected